# Question removed

Tags: discussion, reputation

Today, I get (-42) reputation because of the question removed that mean about 21 questions have been removed ,

- Are these questions removed via user or community?
- If I have answered a question and then it removed, Is it will remove only (-2) or my answer reputation (+15) too?
- Regardless what is the reputation that will be deleted, Is it appropriate solution to delete the user reputation who tries to answer or edit and improve this question at this time and ignore his effort ? if this a community rule so I respect it .but I am wondering is there an appropriate solution that not neglect the user effort.
- What about the edits after 2000 reputation, Is it will cause -2 also if it removed?
- Is this will effect on the `copy editor` badge after it earned ?

Thanks in advance for any clarifications

Comment: Regarding the 15 rep for an accepted answer, it shouldn't be possible to lose that because a question with an accepted answer will never be deleted by the automatic process described by Eric Alexander, nor could it be manually deleted (except maybe by a mod, but even that seems unlikely).

Comment: Many thanks @DanHenderson for your clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They all appear to be of the automatically deleted by community questions.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/roomba

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Eric Alexander ,